# Access JSF Session Attributes in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jsf-2.2

I'm using Omnifaces Faces.setSessionAttribute but I'm not able to access these attributes in authentication provider because Facescontext is null.

Comment: You don't need the `FacesContext`. Those should be stored in the `HttpSession` so getting that from the request should be enough. However ideally you shouldn't access anything in your provider but should be provided by the passed in `Authentication` object. Your provider shouldn't know about the web, JSF, etc.

Comment: Yes I can get the attributes now, thanks a lot

Comment: But regarding accessing session attributes from authentication, I'm doing this because I'm doing custom authentication on 2 steps using user name & password then token sent via mail upon username & password validation, any other ideas are much appreciated

Comment: Neither `HttpSession` or `FacesConext` is the way to go for storing session data in my opinion. It's a lot cleaner (and modern) to use a session scoped bean that you @Inject (in the case of normal EE) or @Autowire (in the case of Spring) into where you need it. It's also a type safe way of storing session data.

Comment: can you explain more why session scoped bean would be better? I think session bean will be stored in server side(memory cost), I will check that because I'm not sure

Comment: Using a session scoped bean makes things transparant. If you have both username/password and a token you need to write a custom `Authentication` implementation that contains that. Your provider ideally should get all it needs for authentication from the passed in `Authentication` object. It shouldn't need to reach out to other injected beans or context related (HTTP session, message session etc) things. All of that should be done in your customized authentication filter.